# Increase NGINX Client_Max_Body_Size via YAML (AKS)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, nginx, yaml

TLDR: Can I utilize my existing deployment YAML (see **dev-deployment.yaml** snippet below) to specify a client_max_body_size to a server or servers in my **nginx ingress**?

Some background:

- I recently added some functionality to an API for uploading images
- Receive this error when attempting uploads in our DEV environment: 413 Request Entity Too Large

  - issue not occurring when running locally
- Preliminary research suggested increasing the **nginx** 'client_max_body_size' greater than the attempted upload size
- Additionally found that setting an annotation like 'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size' in my YAML might achieve the same goal
- This all runs in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

I don't know if it's even possible to configure this setting via this method with the desired outcome at this point.  Just seeing if anyone may have a similar configuration and if they were able to resolve it from a YAML perspective, versus going in and editing **nginx** .conf file(s) in the node agents in AKS.

**dev-deployment.yaml (ingress rules section only)**

```
#ingress rules
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: someApp-ingress-dev
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ui-dev.example.com
    - api1-dev.example.com
    - api2-dev.example.com
    - api3-dev.example.com
    - api4-dev.example.com
    secretName: someApp-secret
  rules:
  - host: ui-dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: someApp-ui-dev
              port:
                number: 80
  - host: structures-dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: someApp-api1-api-dev
              port:
                number: 80

// limited to (2) rules for brevity
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this and side-stepped all that I posed above.

I added the following entry in the **ConfigMap** in **AKS** for my **nginx-ingress** controllers:

```
data:
  client-max-body-size: 40m
```

My pods inherited this (after delete) and applied it to all the server entries in my **default.conf**.  I'll circle back at some point and figure out how to target a specific server entry.